# Do I say "log files on bug ticket" or "log files for bug ticket"?

Tags: prepositions

Do I say "log files on bug ticket" or "log files for bug ticket"? Can I say this:

> I am studying log files, generated after Ben on bug ticket H-201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably phrase that as "I'm studying the log files Ben generated for bug ticket H-201."

Either "for" or "on" could work there. "After" was the preposition that moreso stood out to me as being a bit confusing. That usually indicates something which happens later than something else in chronological order, which doesn't feel like it fits here ("I took a walk after my morning classes").